# How do you remove columns in Azure Cosmos DB View?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm pretty new to NoSQL in general but I'm trying azure's cosmos db to store my logs. I've been really struggling with their UI.

In the image below, I just created a random collection and added a simple entity with 3 fields. All I want to do at this point is so reduce the columns so that I only see the ones I want. Granted I can't remove the first 3 columns, whenever I try to remove any column at all, I get this error and instead of removing the columns it just leave it blank. Now I can't find any documentation for this simple UI (which shouldn't really be the case) so here are some things maybe someone can help me out.

1. How to remove columns. Like in SQL, only display the columns I want?
2. How to create custom query? The query builder here is really limited and unusable to be honest.
3. Is there any other DB Client similar to MongoDB's compass that might make the UI easier?

[image]

Comment: You chose the Table API, which emulates Azure Storage Table service (a legacy key/value store). Unless you're migrating legacy code, I'd strongly suggest using the core (SQL) API instead. And at that point, you can do SQL-style queries (including selecting the properties you want). Plenty of docs for the SQL query stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.How to remove columns. Like in SQL, only display the columns I want?

You could choose your desired columns in the advanced options,but the PartitionKey,RowKey and TimesStamp are default columns in cosmos db table api,you can't remove them in the portal data explorer.

[image]

> 2.How to create custom query?

Same as above situations,it has limitation in the portal UI.

> 3.Is there any other DB Client similar to MongoDB's compass that might make the UI easier?

However,you could download the [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) so that you could easily manage the contents of your storage account.

It's more flexible than portal UI ,such as you could filter the columns,including the default columns.

[image]

However, the general design of the tool UI is similar to the portal UI.

BTW,as @David mentioned in the comment,if you want to query the data more flexible with sql language,you need to consider using [Cosmos DB SQL API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-query-reference) instead of Cosmos DB Table API.

Comment: Thanks @jay-gong this is exactly what I needed. It's just annoying that even for a simple query I'd have to download the desktop tool.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the experience could be quite daunting. As a suggestion, you could try Cerebrata (https://cerebrata.com/) as a cost-effective solution.

The tool basically allows you to remove the desired columns in just a few clicks (as projected in the GIF below). The tool also allows you to edit multiple entities in bulk and more.

[CosmosDB Delete entities Table API - Cerebrata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEwdW.gif)